# Multi-level navigation menu options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am doing a small web project for a friend's business.

I'm looking for a plug and play navigation menu that I can use that supports multi-level navigation.  I'd also like to have as much styling control as possible with the navigation menu.

The best free menu I found on the web was jQuery Superfish.  It does not seem to of been updated in a while and I am wondering if its still a good choice, or are there better alternatives.

I already have jQuery loaded on the site, so I would prefer a plugin that uses jQuery or does not require a lot of additional framework dependencies.

Thanks for the input.

Comment: Looks plenty good enough for me. You might have issues with newer jQuery versions, but other than that, as long as something works cross browser, you're fine.